# JSONb dates: actual dates internally?

Tags: postgresql, date, jsonb

I'm using the postgresql jdbc adapter to migrate a bunch of data into a jsonb field (postgres 9.4).

After importing, date fields look correct but are displayed surrounded with doublequotes.  Is there a way to tell if they are actually stored internally as date values ? If they're strings, I don't think range lookups will be very efficient.

For example, an entry in a `properties` jsonb field looks like this:

`"founded_on": "Sep 1, 2012 12:00:00 AM",`

I can now search on, say,

`SELECT CAST(properties->>'founded_on' AS DATE`

and

`SELECT extract('year' from cast(properties->>'founded_on' as timestamp))`

and both work fine, but don't tell me whether Postgres is reparsing a string value in the jsonb field each time, as a date.

I could create an index where I cast these values to dates, and use that to search, but it seems somewhat inelegant.  I'd really prefer to know that the value stored is a date. Integers and floats appear to be their actual native values, not strings, as in these:

`shares_sold": 5900000,`

`"latitude": 33.561467,`

Any feedback highly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

JSON does not have a "date" type. The JSONB type (added in [Pg 9.4](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4)) maps but [*does not extend* upon JSON primitive types.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) The value seen is what it is, text.

While an index can be added over string properties the current "English prose" format will not be able to participate in *range queries* because such values are not well-ordered over dates.

Different ways of storing well-ordered dates, given the primitive type restrictions.

- Specific [ISO 8601 variation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) (with same timezone); text
- [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or "JavaScript time" with milliseconds; integer
- [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) (see the ['J' date format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html)); numeric

(Equality index probes can be used even if ranges cannot .. provided the values match exactly, which is still subject to using a consistent data representation.)

When applying a range query over the (JSONB / GIN) index convert the DATE values to the appropriate JSON data type (mapped to integer, numeric, text in Pg) used for the "date" property; not the other way.

When fetching the values convert the chosen format to a DATE - it's 'okay' since this is done *after* the range query and 'required' since JSONB does not natively support dates or times.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is excellent. We are going to use unixtime everywhere.