# Is ISO8601 the best date-format for PostgreSQL jsonb when i want to filter by the date?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, jsonb

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I have the following question:

I have a table with just an id-column and a data-column, which uses the jsonb-type. Inside the jsonb-object I have a datetime field. I read in various posts, that I should use the ISO-8601 dateformat to store in the DB.

I want to filter my table by date like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data->'date' > '2016-01-01T00:00'
```

Is this really the best date-format for this purpose?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONb dates: actual dates internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269037/jsonb-dates-actual-dates-internally)

Comment: @Schwern: No, I saw this question before, but I don't care, how the date is stored. But I care about filtering by the date

Comment: That answer also discusses various date formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big advantage of that format is that string order corresponds to date order, so a comparison like the one you quote in your question would actually work as intended.

A second advantage is that a timestamp in that format can easily be converted to a PostgreSQL `timestamp with time zone` value, because the type input function understands this format.

I hope you are not dealing with dates “before Christ”, because it wouldn't work so easily with those.

Comment: If those strings have time zone information (in multiple zones) the string order won't correspond to the date order either.  I think it would always be best to cast it.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO  Your query should produce

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb > timestamp with time zone

If I get it right. In case you change `->` to `->>` it should get a text value instead of jsonb field (which is also not comparable to timestamp).
It should be smth like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (data->>'date')::timestamptz > '2016-01-01T00:00'` to work